# How to display data in cell table blade Laravel according date value

Tags: php, laravel

I need help to display data in the cell table blade according to date data in the MySQL database. If you have any ideas for my problem, please share.

**Result**

[image: result]

**Expected Result**

[image: data display based on date header]

**Controller**

```
public function index_filter(Request $request)
{
    $month1 = $request->month1;
    $month2 = $request->month2;

    $dt = Schedule::where('date', $month1)->value('date');
    $dtx = Schedule::where('employee_id', 1)->get();
    $dtt = Carbon::parse($dt)->daysInMonth;

    $month_label = Carbon::parse($dt)->format('M-Y');

    $data_date = Employee::with([
        'schedule' => function ($q) use ($month1, $month2) {
            $q->whereBetween('date', [$month1, $month2]);
        }
    ])->get();

    $name = DB::table('employees')->get();

    return view('admin.filter-laporan', [
        'dt' => $dt,
        'dtt' => $dtt,
        'dtx' => $dtx,
        'data_date' => $data_date,
        'month_label' => $month_label,
        'month1' => $month1,
        'month2' => $month2,
        'name' => $name
    ]);
}
```

**Blade/View**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">No</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Nama</th>
        <th colspan="{{ $dtt }}" style="text-align: center;">{{ $month_label }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @php
            $number = 1;
        @endphp
        @for ($i = 0; $i < $dtt; $i++)
            <th>{{ $number++ }}</th>
        @endfor
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($data_date as $key => $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
            <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
            @foreach ($item->schedule as $items)
                @if ($items->status == 'D')
                    <td style="background-color: green;">{{$items->date }}</td>
                @endif
                @if ($items->status == 'C')
                    <td style="background-color: yellow;">X</td>
                @endif
                @if ($items->status == 'LD')
                    <td style="background-color: red;">X</td>
                @endif
                @if ($items->status == '')
                    <td>-</td>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 2nd `@foreach` with this one

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $dtt; $i++)
    @foreach ($item->schedule as $items)
        @if(date('d', strtotime($items->date)) == $i)
            @if ($items->status == 'D')                    
                <td style="background-color: green;">{{ $items->date }}</td>
            @endif
            @if ($items->status == 'C')
                <td style="background-color: yellow;">X</td>
            @endif
            @if ($items->status == 'LD')
                <td style="background-color: red;">X</td>
            @endif
            @if ($items->status == '')
                <td>-</td>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

Comment: still same sir, i've tried make if conditional with carbon::parse($items->date)->format('d') == '01' to '30' but if date are have more than 2 data, the next date will be displayed in the next table

Comment: you mean next row / <tr></tr>

Comment: no sir, i made the if conditional like if conditional else <td></td>.